# Clear input stream after fgets set null char before newline

Tags: c, fgets

I have a program where the user enters two inputs. Being that I can't control what the user enters, the user can go past the fixed size of the array. Since `fgets()` <strike>appends</strike> retains a newline to the end before the null character, in the event that a newline cannot fit when the user goes beyond the intended size, the null character truncates the input. Does the newline character when the user hits enter still exist in the input stream? If so, is this the reason why `fgets()`skips the second time because of the newline from the first input?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char str[5];
    fgets(str,5,stdin);
    printf("Output:%s",str);

    fgets(str,5,stdin);
    printf("Output:%s",str);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input**
   `ABCDE\n`

**Output**

```
Output:ABCDOutput:E
```

After reading this SO answer [fgets() isn't prompting user a second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227981/fgets-isnt-prompting-user-a-second-time)
, the issue seems to be not flushing the input stream via `fflush(stdin)`, but I've heard conflicting information saying as this leads to undefined behavior. My last question is, what would be the appropriate way to clear the input stream if it's the retained newline that's causing issues?

Comment: Read repeatedly until nothing is left.

Comment: The size passed to `fgets` will include any newline *and* the terminating `'\0'`. If you want to understand, at least put some newlines and `[brackets]` in the output, to show what is happening, such as `printf("Output:[%s]\n",str);`

Comment: "Since fgets() appends a newline to the end before the null character," is incorrect.  `fgets()` reads and saves a new line like any character.  It does append a _null character_. and does stop after reading a `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux Yes. I shouldn't have said append but instead retained given one.

Comment: Re the first two questions: it is not just a newline that remains in the input buffer but `E\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the user can go past the fixed size of the array. Since `fgets()` appends a newline to the end before the null character

No, it does not.  It writes characters read from the input into the provided buffer, up to *and including* the first newline, or until the specified buffer size is exhausted (less one byte for the string terminator), or until an error occurs or the end of the stream is reached, whichever comes first.  The newline is not invented by `fgets()`; it comes from the input.

> , in the event that a newline cannot fit when the user goes beyond the intended size, the null character truncates the input. Does the newline character when the user hits enter still exist in the input stream?

All characters entered by the user and not copied into the buffer remain waiting to be read in the stream.  That will include the newline, if the user entered one.

> If so, is this the reason why fgets()skips the second time because of the newline from the first input?

`fgets()` does not skip, but it does pick up where the previous call left off transferring characters from input to the buffer.  No characters are lost.  That means that the second call returns part of the first input line if the first call did not return the whole thing.  You need to account one way or another for the possibility that the input does not conform to your line-length expectations.

> the issue seems to be not flushing the input stream via `fflush(stdin)`,

No, it isn't.  Flushing is for sending buffered *output* to the underlying output device.  Flushing an input stream produces undefined behavior.  In principle, that could manifest as a buffer dump, and a given implementation might even specify such behavior, ***but you don't want that*** because there may be more data buffered than you want to get rid of.

> but I've heard conflicting information saying as this leads to undefined behavior. My last question is, what would be the appropriate way to clear the input stream if it's the retained newline that's causing issues?

You read from the input until you've read the newline.  There are plenty of I/O functions to choose from to accomplish this.  `fgets()` itself might prove convenient, since you're already using it:

```
char str[5];

if (fgets(str, 5, stdin)) {
    printf("Output:%s", str);
    // read and consume the tail of the line, if any (overwrites str)
    while (!strchr(str, '\n') && fgets(str, 5, stdin)) { /* empty */ }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`fgets()` reads until

1) New-line
2) Buffer is full
3) End-of-file
4) Input error (rare)

This code reads and takes care of #3 & #4

```
 #define N 5
 char buf[N];
 if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
   // Handle EOF or Error
   return EOF;
 }
```

To distinguish if a `'\n'` is present ...  (#2 from #1)

```
 // look for a lack of \n
 if (strchr(buf, '\n') == NULL) {
```

And if so, read until it is found or `EOF`.

```
   int ch;
   while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
 }
```

--

Do not use the following code.  It can be exploited by reading a *null character* as the first character.

```
 size_t len = strlen(buf);
 if (buf[len - 1] != '\n') {  // bad way to detect \n
```

Could use

```
 if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] != '\n') {  // Good
```

Comment: When you say _exploited_, do you mean that in a malicious way or a logical flaw when the length of the buffer is zero that `buf[0-1]`?

Comment: @Miket25 In a malicious way.  `fgets()` reads and saves a _null character_ just like any other.  so it is fairly easy to cause the first character in `buf[]` to be `'\0'`.  Then `buf[strlen(buf) - 1]` causes UB.  Recall it is not `buf[0-1]`, but `buf[(size_t)0-1]` or `buf[SIZE_MAX]`.

Answer (score 4):

> Being that I can't control what the user enters...

No, you cannot.

> the user can go past the fixed size of the array.

Right.  This is always a concern.  However, In general you'll want to arrange things so that this rarely happens.

For example, if you really want to limit the user to (say) a 4-character-long input string, let him type whatever he wants, then see how much he typed, and if it was more than your limit, print a nice error message or something.  But I do not recommend calling `fgets(str, 5, stdin)` if you're expecting 4 characters of input plus a newline, because it's just way too hard to recover when (not if) the user types too much.

> in the event that a newline cannot fit when the user goes beyond the intended size, the null character truncates the input. Does the newline character when the user hits enter still exist in the input stream?

Absolutely yes.

> If so, is this the reason why fgets()skips the second time because of the newline from the first input?

Pretty much yes.

I recommend allocating a much bigger buffer, and then proceeding something like this:

```
char inpbuf[512);
if(fgets(inpbuf, sizeof(inpbuf), stdin) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "end of file\n");
    return;
}
char *p = strrchr(inpbuf, '\n');
if(p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "looks like you typed *way* too much\n");
    return;
}
*p = '\0';        /* erase the \n */
if(strlen(inpbuf) > 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "you typed too much (max 4)\n");
    return;
}
strcpy(str, inpbuf);
printf("Output:%s", str);
```

One glitch with this code as written, though: if the user hits the end-of-file key (control-D on Unix/Linux) before hitting Return, you'll falsely get the "looks like you typed *way* too much" message.

Comment: UV for the "Q:Being that I can't control what the user enters... A:No, you cannot". unless code has a `StompOnUserOnLongLine(5);`

Answer (score 3):

If the string read by `fgets` doesn't end in a newline, you know it's still in the buffer.  In that case, call `getchar` in a loop until you get a newline.

```
fgets(str,5,stdin);
printf("Output:%s",str);
if (strchr(str, '\n') == NULL) {
    int c; 
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
}

fgets(str,5,stdin);
printf("Output:%s",str);
```

Comment: The input from file may not always contain a newline, if it was the last line.

Comment: @WeatherVane True, in that case end-of-file will eventually occur and `while (getchar() != '\n');` will be an infinite loop

Comment: And the loop code should, therefore, be: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` to handle EOF sensibly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good call.  Edited.